# Chatbot using Huggingface Transformers

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot, huggingface-transformers, blenderbot

I would like to use Huggingface Transformers to implement a chatbot. Currently, I have the code shown below. The transformer model already takes into account the history of past user input.

Is there something else (additional code) I have to take into account for building the chatbot?

Second, how can I modify my code to run with TensorFlow instead of PyTorch?

Later on, I also plan to fine-tune the model on other data. I also plan to test different models such as BlenderBot and GPT2. I think to test this different models it should be as easy as replacing the corresponding model in `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")` and `AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")`

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")

for step in range(5):
    # encode the new user input, add the eos_token and return a tensor in Pytorch
    new_user_input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input(">> User:") + tokenizer.eos_token, return_tensors='pt')

    # append the new user input tokens to the chat history
    bot_input_ids = torch.cat([chat_history_ids, new_user_input_ids], dim=-1) if step > 0 else new_user_input_ids

    # generated a response while limiting the total chat history to 1000 tokens, 
    chat_history_ids = model.generate(bot_input_ids, max_length=1000, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)

    # pretty print last ouput tokens from bot
    print("DialoGPT: {}".format(tokenizer.decode(chat_history_ids[:, bot_input_ids.shape[-1]:][0], skip_special_tokens=True)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using the `DialoGPT` model with Tensorflow:

```py
from transformers import TFAutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BlenderbotTokenizer, TFBlenderbotForConditionalGeneration
import tensorflow as tf

chat_bots = {
    'BlenderBot': [BlenderbotTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/blenderbot-400M-distill'), TFT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('facebook/blenderbot-400M-distill')],
    'DialoGPT': [AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small"), TFAutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")],
} 
key = 'DialoGPT'
tokenizer, model = chat_bots[key]

for step in range(5):
    new_user_input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input(">> User:") + tokenizer.eos_token, return_tensors='tf')
    if step > 0:
      bot_input_ids = tf.concat([chat_history_ids, new_user_input_ids], axis=-1)  
    else:
      bot_input_ids = new_user_input_ids

    chat_history_ids = model.generate(bot_input_ids, max_length=1000, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)

    print(key + ": {}".format(tokenizer.decode(chat_history_ids[:, bot_input_ids.shape[-1]:][0], skip_special_tokens=True)))
```

```
>> User:How are you?
DialoGPT: I'm here
>> User:Why are you here
DialoGPT: I'm here
>> User:But why
DialoGPT: I'm here
>> User:Where is here
DialoGPT: Where is where?
>> User:Here
DialoGPT: Where is here?
```

If you want to compare different chatbots, you might want to adapt their decoder parameters, because they are not always identical. For example, using `BlenderBot` and a `max_length` of 50 you get this kind of response with the current code:

```
>> User:How are you?
BlenderBot: ! I am am great! how how how are are are???
```

In general, you should ask yourself which special characters are important for a chatbot (depending on your domain) and which characters should / can be omitted?

You should also experiment with different decoding methods such as greedy search, beam search, random sampling, top-k sampling, and nucleus sampling and find out what works best for your use case. For more information on this topic check out this [post](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate)

Comment: Thank you very much. The conversation with the chatbot you posted does not make that much sense. ;) Are on Huggingface no pre-trained models for GPT2 and BlenderBot available that work out of the box?

Comment: There are.. as posted in my answer but as I said they need different parameters probably and that is why you would have to adapt your code a bit.